# Reactive Extensions in .NET: How can one cancel a Timeout() early?

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

Currently I have something like this:

```
await Observable.FromEventPattern<WriteConfirmationEventArgs>(
    h => this.WriteCompleted += h,
    h => this.WriteCompleted -= h)
    .Select(x => x.EventArgs.Id)
    .FirstAsync(x => Guid.Equals(x, dto.Id))
    .Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
```

which seems to work fine. However, there is an event that occurs in the same class, upon which I need to cancel the timeout; it should NOT wait the full 10 seconds.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: So, you want to this observable sequence to exit when the other event is triggered?

Comment: Yes--whether it ends with a natural `TimeoutException` or some other exception resulting from a cancellation, I just want it to end (and whatever disposals that need to happen, to happen)

Comment: The solution I provided will terminate the sequence without throwing an exception, i.e., the `onCompleted` delegate will be invoked, not the `onError` delegate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this:

Assume that you have the first Observable in a variable called `observable1` (that is based on the `WriteCompleted` event).

To make this more clear, here is the definition of `observable1`:

```
var observable1 = Observable.FromEventPattern<WriteConfirmationEventArgs>(
    h => this.WriteCompleted += h,
    h => this.WriteCompleted -= h)
    .Select(x => x.EventArgs.Id)
    .FirstAsync(x => Guid.Equals(x, dto.Id))
    .Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
```

Create another Observable that is based on the other event like this:

```
var observable2 = Observable.FromEventPattern<OtherEventEventArgs>(
            h => this.OtherEvent += h,
            h => this.OtherEvent -= h);
```

Then create another Observable by composing the two Observables with the `TakeUntil` method like this:

```
var new_observable = observable1.TakeUntil(observable2);
```

And then subscribe to this new Observable instead of `observable1`

Comment: From what I understood from the question, OP does not want to time out if the other event is triggered,  he simply wants to exit the first sequence.

Comment: I understood this from "cancel the timeout"

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean

Comment: Thanks--it worked great. Your comment that it won't throw an exception (but rather OnCompleted) wasn't true in my case; it actually threw an InvalidOperationException, with the message "sequence contains no elements". This turns out to be ideal for my case anyways.